# Does magnetism only work on ferrous objects?

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity

Ordinary magnets can attract only ferrous objects (correct if i am wrong), but celestial bodies attract almost anything (including light). Are these different types of magnetism?

Comment: Celestial bodies attract things due to gravity not magnetism

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism. Magnets can also attract nickel and cobalt.

Comment: Magnetism can affect most anything. You can, for example, levitate frogs (the author of this experiment earned an igNoble, though) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_levitation#Direct_diamagnetic_levitation - regular magnets, though, will only affect in any measurable ways some kinds of metals.

Comment: Echoing @Renan's comment, see http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/23523/2451 Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15366/2451

Comment: From the downvotes, i assume that this was a very stupid question. I am not a physics graduate and couldn't find anyone to answer this around. For newbies like me a one liner (like what @bretsky gave) is enough. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magnetism and gravity are very different things. Gravity is not a form of magnetism, nor is magnetism a form of gravity.
http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity
http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetism

Comment: I kind of assumed that they are the same. This clears up my confusion, thanks!.